How to apply a filter in Apache Superset to a column not in the final query
I'm currently working with Apache Superset and have encountered a specific challenge. I need to apply a filter to a column that isn't present in the final query output but exists within a subquery in the FROM clause. Does anyone have insights on how to implement this? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated as I navigate this issue.
Thank you in advance for your help!
Only i expecting a explication or posibilities

SO is for programming questions

If you have a situation like this:
WITH    -- S a m p l e    D a t a :
    items (ID, ITEM_NAME) As
      ( Select 1, 'Item 1' Union All 
        Select 2, 'Item 2' Union All 
        Select 3, 'Item 3' 
      ),
   prices (ID, PRICE, ACTIVE) AS
      ( Select 1, 10, 'No'  Union All 
        Select 1, 12, 'Yes' Union All 
        Select 2, 25, 'Yes' Union All 
        Select 3, 20, 'No'  Union All 
        Select 3, 22, 'Yes' 
    )

... with a subquery selecting PRICE_DIFF_PCT column and you want to filter the result to just rows having the difference greater than 10% without that column in selection list of the main (outer) query - the described situation should work ...
Select  p.ID, p.ITEM_NAME, p.PRICE_NEW, p.PRICE_OLD
From    ( Select i.ID, i.ITEM_NAME,
                 p1.PRICE as PRICE_NEW, p2.PRICE as PRICE_OLD,
                 (p1.PRICE - p2.PRICE) * 100 / p2.PRICE as PRICE_DIFF_PCT
          From   items i
          Left Join prices p1 ON(p1.ID = i.ID And p1.ACTIVE = 'Yes')
          Left Join prices p2 ON(p2.ID = i.ID And p2.ACTIVE = 'No')
        ) p
Where   PRICE_DIFF_PCT > 10

/*    R e s u l t :
id  item_name   price_new   price_old
--  ---------   ---------   ---------
 1  Item 1             12          10   */

... and if it doesn't for any reason, one of the alternative options to do it is to declare your subquery as a cte (named it price_diffs) and use it in the from clause of the main query and, as a correlated subquery, with EXISTS() in where clause ...
   price_diffs AS     -- Declare your subquery as a cte
     ( Select i.ID, i.ITEM_NAME,
              p1.PRICE as PRICE_NEW, p2.PRICE as PRICE_OLD,
             (p1.PRICE - p2.PRICE) * 100 / p2.PRICE as PRICE_DIFF_PCT
       From   items i
       Left Join prices p1 ON(p1.ID = i.ID And p1.ACTIVE = 'Yes')
       Left Join prices p2 ON(p2.ID = i.ID And p2.ACTIVE = 'No')
     )

--    M a i n    S Q L :
Select  pd.ID, pd.ITEM_NAME, pd.PRICE_NEW, pd.PRICE_OLD
From    price_diffs pd
Where   EXISTS(Select 1 From price_diffs Where ID = pd.ID And PRICE_DIFF_PCT > 10)

/*    R e s u l t :
id  item_name   price_new   price_old
--  ---------   ---------   ---------
 1  Item 1             12          10   */

See the fiddle here.
